# Sum all values in a column with an especified header

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

I have a file which has sections with different tables. I want to sum all the values contained within each column with the header N*dN

For example:

```
omega (dN/dS) = 999.00000

dN & dS for each branch

 branch          t       N       S   dN/dS      dN      dS  N*dN  S*dS

  11..6      0.000   532.0   266.0 999.0000  0.0000  0.0000   3.0   0.0
  11..7      0.000   532.0   266.0 999.0000  0.0000  0.0000   4.0   0.0
  11..12     0.000   532.0   266.0 999.0000  0.0000  0.0000   0.5   0.0

omega (dN/dS) = 1.00000

dN & dS for each branch

 branch          t       N       S   dN/dS      dN      dS  N*dN  S*dS

  11..6      0.000   532.0   266.0 999.0000  0.0000  0.0000   7.0   0.0
  11..7      0.000   532.0   266.0 999.0000  0.0000  0.0000   2.0   0.0
  11..12     0.000   532.0   266.0 999.0000  0.0000  0.0000   0.4   0.0
```

Desired output:

```
7.5
9.4
```

Maybe some modification of

```
awk '{s+=$8}END{print s}'
```

where I can specify the title of the column and make it print the separate results of each sum, not the sum of the sums...

Comment: How shall awk detect the header and data areas? Maybe you can pass the relevant line numbers to tha `awk` call, might be easier.

Comment: I tried with the column number, but I don't know how to incorporate the header factor. The file has more tables with 8 rows but not the right header, so I need to specify that. Awk may not be the right choice.

Comment: Is the content of the header line guaranteed to be always the same?

Comment: It is guaranteed to be always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` in this way (assuming the content are always followed by the matched header and same counts in all + no empty lines happened between them).

```
awk 'f{s+=$8;f++} ($8=="N*dN"){f=1} (f>4){print s;f=s=0}' infile
```

Or in general case, use it as like below. It will sum till next `N*dN` seen in column#8:

```
awk 'f{s+=$8} (f &&$8=="N*dN"){print s;f=s=0} ($8=="N*dN"){f=1} END{print s}' infile
```

Comment: Worked great! 

I tried to adjust the command to do the same with S*dS like this:

awk 'f{s+=$9;f++} ($9=="S*dS"){f=1} (f>4){print s;f=s=0}'

But it did'nt work.. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Apparently the asterisc doesn't show in my comment, but I put it.

Comment: It does work to me

Answer (score 1):

Another ***awk*** approach:

```
awk '$8=="N*dN"{ r=NR; if(s) print s; s=0 }r && NR-r<5{ s+=$8 }END{ print s }' file
```

The output:

```
7.5
9.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is not funny thing to with the eyes of a programmer, but it is really quick and it is okay for simple tasks.

As we can see, all of the interesting rows contain the string `..`, so we can filter them with a `grep`:

```
grep -F '..' <input.txt|awk 'BEGIN{s=0}{s+=$8}END{print s}'
```

To do this with multiple columns, you have to use multiple variables (for example, `$a`, `$b`, `$c`, ...).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

`(awk '{if($8=="N*dN")next}{print 0$8}' data.txt | tr '\n' '+'; echo 0) | bc -l`

`{if($8=="N*dN")next}` discard useless headers

`{print 0$8}` prints the 8th field with a leading '0' (will replace empty fields with 0).

`tr '\n' '+'; echo 0` will replace end of lines with '+' and and a trailing 0

`bc -l` will sum all that